# DigiKam update not showing thumbnails after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, thumbnails, digikam

Upgraded Ubuntu to 20.04.02 and digiKam (upgraded to 6.4.0) now shows only handful of thumbnails (out of about 12,000 in the db). db location (Settings, Configure Digikam, etc) is correct. Digikam sees all the albums and I see small thumbnails on the left when in Similarity browse. How can I get the main Thumbnails to show in the center screen?

I have examined thumbnails-digikam.db with DB Browser for SQLite and the thumbnails/binaries are all there. But digiKam sees only a few.

This is not the first experience with this. Two times previously I upgraded from digiKam 4.- to 6.4.0 and had this problem but thought it was fault of Ubuntu 18.-. But same problem with 20.04.

I have reinstalled digiKam and tried to id missing dependencies but not so far. Is hair pulling time.

Uninstalled digikam 6.4.0 and installed 7.1.0, same problem. Definite a problem with ubuntu some dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem by purging digikam and re-installing 7.1.0. Works.
The command I used:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove digikam
```

then loaded with an appimage.